# For reporting testcases to Xray we are using Karate Runtime Hooks issue here is testcases are not getting executed while using hooks & hooks code ran

Tags: runtime, hook, karate

For reporting testcases to Xray we have developed generic code using Karate Runtime Hooks ,a class that implements RuntimeHook ,so that anyone writing test cases in Karate can invoke that coode using hook and include that in the runner file as below
[image]

Here feature files having simple login statements are working fine but if the feauture files contains call to another feature files like below ,
[image]

then test cases doesnt run and only hook if running giving the below error please advice on how to rectify this , we tried using all versions from 1.0.1 till 1.1.0.RC5

[image]

Comment: hooks are meant for advanced users who know how to use java well, so you are on your own. this is not something the developers of karate can support you with, you have to figure this out on your own, look at the code and contribute improvements to karate if required. look at this example if it helps: https://github.com/kirksl/karate-maven-gradle/blob/5c4580372dc6f067bdb6aebb5803ac166b9111f5/src/test/java/KarateHook.java